# How to specify a class that may contain another class

Tags: c#, class

I want to create a class that have a class but this second class may be different each time the first class is called. For example:

```
public class ServerResponseObject
{
    public string statusCode { get; set; }
    public string errorCode { get; set; }
    public string errorDescription { get; set; }
    public Object obj { get; set; }

    public ServerResponseObject(Object obje)
    {
        obj = obje;
    }
}   

public class TVChannelObject
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteChannel { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string packageid { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelCategoryObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do it to call the `ServerResponseObject` with different objects each time, once with `TVChannelObject` and once with `ChannelCategoryObject`?

Comment: You could create an interface `IServerResponseObject` and let both classes implement it. Then make it `public IServerResponseObject Obj { get; set; }`

Comment: As an aside, C# naming conventions recommend using Pascal case for properties.  Unless your internal guidelines specify otherwise, I would recommend getting into the habit of using this approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [generic type parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx):

```
public class ServerResponseObject<T>
{
    public ServerResponseObject(T obj)
    {
        Obj = obj;
    }

    public T Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think that was what I was looking for, thank you!!